# Mandar valor numérico de um Enum pela requisição HTTP no Java

Tags: java, json, http, java-8, enums

Estou com um problema no meu sistema, no meu Back-end em `Java com Spring Boot` eu tenho uma classe que tem uma propriedade que é do tipo de um `Enum` que eu criei, e o meu Front-end que é em `Angular` quando faz uma requisição para retornar um valor do tipo dessa classe o valor que fica na propriedade do `Enum` não é o valor numérico do `Enum` e sim o nome.

Exemplo, tenho um `Enum` `Status.enum` que tem os valores `ATIVO(1)` e `DESATIVO(2)`, quando mando esse `Enum` por requisição HTTP ele ta retornando: `{ "status": "ATIVO" }`. E o certo seria retornar pela requisição o seguinte: `{ "status": 1 }`. Já tentei sobrescrever o `toString()` pra ele retornar o valor numérico em String mas nem isso consegui.

Meu Enum:

```
public enum DiaSemanaEnum {

    SEGUNDA(1),
    TERCA(2),
    QUARTA(3),
    QUINTA(4),
    SEXTA(5),
    SABADO(6),
    DOMINGO(7);

    private Integer codigo;

    DiaSemanaEnum(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public static DiaSemanaEnum getObjetoEnum(Integer codigo) {

        for (DiaSemanaEnum dse : DiaSemanaEnum.values()) {
            if (dse.getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
                return dse;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public static DiaSemanaEnum getObjetoEnum(String nome) {

        for (DiaSemanaEnum dse : DiaSemanaEnum.values()) {
            if (dse.name().equals(nome)) {
                return dse;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

}
```

Minha classe que tem o Enum como uma das propriedades:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfiguracaoAgendaProfissional {

    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Profissional profissional;

    private DiaSemanaEnum diaSemana;

    private String descricao;

    private LocalTime horaInicio;

    private LocalTime horaFim;

    private List<ConfiguracaoAgendaProfissionalIntervalo> intervalos = null;


    public ConfiguracaoAgendaProfissional(){

    }

    @JsonCreator
    public ConfiguracaoAgendaProfissional(@JsonProperty("id") Long id, @JsonProperty("diaSemana") Integer diaSemana,
                                      @JsonProperty("descricao") String descricao, @JsonProperty("horaInicio") LocalTime horaInicio,
                                      @JsonProperty("horaFim") LocalTime horaFim) {
        this.id = id;
        this.diaSemana = diaSemana != null ? DiaSemanaEnum.getObjetoEnum(diaSemana) : null;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
        this.horaFim = horaFim;
    }

    public ConfiguracaoAgendaProfissional(Long id, Profissional profissional, Integer diaSemana, String descricao,
                                      LocalTime horaInicio, LocalTime horaFim) {

        this.id = id;
        this.profissional = profissional;
        this.diaSemana = DiaSemanaEnum.getObjetoEnum(diaSemana);
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
        this.horaFim = horaFim;
    }

    public ConfiguracaoAgendaProfissional(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Antes eu estava tendo um problema para mandar um valor do tipo Enum do Front-end para o Back-end e consegui resolver com o `@JsonCreator` e o `@JsonProperty` mas agr meu problema é contrario, pois quero mandar um valor certo do tipo Enum para o Front-end.

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Comment: Poste o código da sua classe Java e do Enum

Comment: Não vejo necessidade disso pois é uma pergunta bem generica mas vou postar mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui achar uma "solução", no Enum coloca a seguinte anotação:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
public enum DiaSemanaEnum { .....
```

isso retorna o valor numérico pelo JSON, só que, no meu case eu coloquei os valores (por exemplo) `LIVRE(1), OCUPADO(2)`, só que ele esta retornando não o valor que eu coloquei no Enum e sim a posição dele, tipo, o `LIVRE(1)` não esta retornando 1, e sim 0 porque é a posição dele. Esse foi o unico problema q encontrei, de resto ta tudo deboa.